# What are options of open source or cheap user tracking software that can be self-hosted?

Tags: google-analytics, piwik

We can't use Google Analytics because we can't upload user data to servers other than our own.  So, given that, what are the good open source or cheap solutions that we can host ourselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/), [Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) and [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) are all open source, self-hosted solutions for analytics. Piwik is probably the solution that most closely follows Google Analytics and is billed as "an open source alternative to Google Analytics."

Answer (score 0):

[Mint](http://haveamint.com/) is a very popular self hosted tracking solution, its not free, but it's around $30 per site.

Answer (score 0):

[analog](http://www.analog.cx/), which is written by an ex-Cambridge statistician, is free (in both senses), blazingly fast, doesn't tell you things it thinks are unknowable, and explains why not.